# iphone app with sql server database make sense?

Tags: ios, iphone, database, ios7, ios8

I'm hiring an iphone developer to develop an iphone 6 app. He only develops front-end, and he only needs the APIs for database access. So I will hire someone else to develop those API calls.

Currently, I have a sql server instance installed in our server that we use for several other projects. So I was thinking of using that sql server instance as backend for our iphone app.

So my question, is sql server an adecuate database to be used for an iphone/smartphone app? I can install any other database, but I prefer sql server because, 1) it's already installed, 2) I know how to use it well.

The database for the iphone app is small, but there has to be a database to store a few things. Also, eventually, there will be an android version later on.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean you are hiring a developer to develop an iPhone app, not just an iPhone 6 app (that's not allowed - you must support all 3.5", 4" and larger iPhones).

Comment: Is your question about a database on a server your app will access or are you talking about a database on the actual iOS device?

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL server can be adequate to you needs, but first question is : does it has to be online (shared datas, data can be updated by someone else than the app user) or only stored on iPhone ?

If online : the app can NOT call a distant database server on its own, you will have to make a webservice that your app will use to get your datas.

If it can be stored on iPhone : it can be done by using a SQLite database or CoreData

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL server database as the backend and you want to integrate with your IOS app, then are a number of ways. The one I use is

You can build a service/web tier providing RESTful APIs (ideal), SOAP services or even web applications which interact with database. If you can use a number of technologies such as MS .NET WebAPIs, Apache CXF/Jersey even NodeJS bases serverside JavaScript etc.,

If you use XCode to build IPhone App, then you can integrate with the services using standard IOS APIs. If you are building a mobile app (Hybrid or HTML5), you can easily integrate with RESTful APIs

These services you build in the backend can be re-used. This means you can either use Android, IOS, HTML5 or any other front end integrate with this back end. The technology in the backend doesn't matter really.

If you think that the App will also update the data in the database, then you need to make sure that the security layer is implemented between your app and services. You may use Oauth and/or many such providers to implement this.